# How to write a batchfile that can copy text in webpage using mozillafirefox?

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
start firefox http://stackoverflow.com
```

How can I make a batch file that can find a string or text in website then copy it into notepad?

Comment: Why the `vbscript` tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `curl` or `wget` to download a webpage into a local file. Then you can use  `FINDSTR` or similar to locate the string in the file. Then you can start `Notepad` using `START`. And you can send whatever the string is to `Notepad` using `SendKeys`.

Or you can extract the string using `FINDSTR` into a new file and then open that file with `Notepad` by passing the filename as a parameter.

**Example**:

```
REM Get main page from hp.com into local file called "hp.txt"
curl www.hp.com > hp.txt

REM Look for all occurences of word "laptop" without worrying about upper/lower case and save in new file called "usefulstuff.txt"
FINDSTR /i Laptop hp.txt    > usefulstuff.txt

REM Start Notepad with the usefulstuff from HP webpage
notepad usefulstuff.txt
```

Comment: windows curl can be found at http://curl.haxx.se/download.html and wget at http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm

Comment: i don't familiarized using the curl or wget sir im only want to know batch scripting and im a beginner for batchfile making.Can you give me some sample batchscript code sir?Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look now. I have added an example.

Comment: The only way you can do it in pure batch code without resorting to wget, curl, vbscript or powershell is to use [bitsadmin](http://ss64.com/nt/bitsadmin.html) but keep in mind that bitsadmin has been depricated in lieu of the BITS cmdlets in powershell.